# COOKIE хранятся в пределах одной папки

Tags: php

Такая проблема: COOKIE почему-то хранятся только в пределах одной папки. Например, на сайте перешел в папку `site.ru/load/index.php` , на этой странице записал куки:

```
setcookie("us", 1, time()+60*60*24*30);
```

перешел на `site.ru` , вывожу куки

```
echo $_COOKIE['us'];
```

Пусто! Перехожу на `site.ru/load/index.php` - куки есть, выводит 1, то что я и записывал. 
Раньше работал с куки и все было отлично.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: только куки хранятся на клиенте, если что

Comment: Странно, так бывает, когда вы задаете path в setcookie(), однако, у вас он не задается. Посмотрите в браузере, что в cookie записано - установлен ли в ней путь?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
setcookie('membername', 'Alex', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 
 "/", "www.mysite.com");
```

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Не понятно, ни в чем решение заключается, ни в чем была изначальная проблема.

Comment: @razzwan, у автора папка - это uri.